# python: How to improve the speed of merging two DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have two DataFrames called `a` and `b`. All columns of `a` should be matched with the column `keyB` of DataFrame `b`. I define a `match` function as follows to achieve it, but the speed of the code is low as the
DataFrame of `a` and `b` actually have a larger shape. So now I want to improve the speed of matching two DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

start=time.time()
a=pd.DataFrame({'key1':[1,5,1],'key2':[1,2,11]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'keyB':[1,2,3,4,5],'other':['q','q','w','w','r']})

def match(num,a,b,col):
    aFeat=a.iloc[num:num+1]
    bFeat=b[b['keyB'].isin([a[col].loc[num]])]
    aFeat.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    bFeat.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    new=pd.concat([aFeat,bFeat],axis=1)
    return new

newb=pd.DataFrame({})
for col in ['key1','key2']:
    newa=pd.DataFrame({})
    for num in range(len(a)):
        newa=pd.concat([newa,match(num,a,b,col)],axis=0)
    newa.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    del newa[col]
    newb.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    newb=pd.concat([newb,newa],axis=1)
    newb = newb.rename(columns={'keyB': 'keyB_'+col, 'other': 'other_'+col})

print(newb)
end=time.time()
print('time:',end-start)
```

`Input:`

```
a    key1  key2
0     1     1
1     5     2
2     1    11

b    keyB other
0     1     q
1     2     q
2     3     w
3     4     w
4     5     r
```

`Output:`

```
   key2  keyB_key1 other_key1  key1  keyB_key2 other_key2
0     1          1          q     1        1.0          q
1     2          5          r     5        2.0          q
2    11          1          q     1        NaN        NaN
```

`Used time:`

```
time: 0.015628576278686523
```

Hopefully for advice of improving the performance of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by `b` in loop for append each Series to list and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all together:

```
s = b.set_index('keyB')['other']
print (s)
keyB
1    q
2    q
3    w
4    w
5    r
Name: other, dtype: object

dfs = []
for col in ['key1','key2']:
    dfs.append(a[col])
    val = a[col].map(s).rename('other_' + col)
    dfs.append(pd.Series(np.where(val.notnull(), a[col], np.nan), name='keyB_' + col))
    dfs.append(val)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
   key1  keyB_key1 other_key1  key2  keyB_key2 other_key2
0     1        1.0          q     1        1.0          q
1     5        5.0          r     2        2.0          q
2     1        1.0          q    11        NaN        NaN
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = [b.merge(a[[col]], left_on='keyB', right_on=col)
        .rename(columns={'keyB':'keyB_'+col,'other':'other_'+col}) for col in ['key1','key2']]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
   keyB_key1 other_key1  key1  keyB_key2 other_key2  key2
0          1          q     1        1.0          q   1.0
1          1          q     1        2.0          q   2.0
2          5          r     5        NaN        NaN   NaN
```